# Entity Framework - list AspNetUsers with roles on admin page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an admin page where someone can go in and make some changes in the database.  I want them to be able to view all non-admin users and edit them as well.  After digging around online, I have figured out how to list out the users by email address and I have a Roles column.  But the value showing up under Roles is not quite correct.  It is the UserID in the AspNetUserRoles table.
Here is my AdminController code that is grabbing the users and roles:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            model.AppUsers = db.Users
        .Include("Roles")
        .Select(u =>
            new ManagerUserViewModel
            {
                UserID = u.Id,
                UserName = u.UserName,
                Email = u.Email,
                Roles = u.Roles.ToList()
            }
        ).ToList();
        };

        return View(model);
```

And here is my ManagerUserViewModel:

```
public class ManagerUserViewModel
{
    public String UserID { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if any other code is needed.

Here is what I am getting output on the page now:
[image]

Comment: IdentityUserRole should be a combination of UserId and RoleId.  Are you sure it doesn't contain what you want? I'd expect an error to be thrown if this wasn't true.  Or is it the role name you're after?

Comment: I want the roll name to be listed along side the user email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access the UserManager instance?  If so it has a GetRoles function which takes a userId and returns a List of roles.

```
 using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
 {
        model.AppUsers = db.Users
    .Include("Roles")
    .Select(u =>
        new ManagerUserViewModel
        {
            UserID = u.Id,
            UserName = u.UserName,
            Email = u.Email
        }
    ).ToList();
 };
 foreach(var user in model.AppUser){
      user.Roles = userManager.GetRoles(user.UserId);
 }
```

You'll need to update your viewmodel

```
 public IEnumerable<String> Roles { get; set; }
```

If you don't have the UserManager you should be able to get it from the OwinContext

```
 var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

Comment: This looks close to what I want.  But I'm not sure how to get access to the UserManager instance.  I know that is in AccountController.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to get the UserManager. Put that above your 'using' statement.

Comment: I made it "var userManager = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager<User>>();" and it fixed that error

Comment: Great. Or HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>() should work too, that's what's in the default AccountController of an MVC project.

Comment: That seems to work better, fixed another error too.  Now when I run it, I get a different error.  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String] GetRoles[ApplicationUser,String](Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2[app.Models.ApplicationUser,System.String], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Fair enough. That's happening because Linq to Entities is trying to convert that statement into SQL and can't.  I've moved the Role logic after the initial users have been assigned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79028/discussion-between-peteg-and-dmikester1).